# Get list of dates for this current week only using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am having some trouble recently regarding an sql query.

I have a table called calender and it it I have calender_id as primary key,calender_start_date.I have some dates like

```
2017-03-02,2017-03-09,2017-03-27,2017-03-30,2017-03-31,2017-03-17.
```

I want to filter out this holiday of this current week.for example 
`2017-03-27,2017-03-30 and 2017-03-31` only

How can I do that using in my sql. Please help.
 Thank You

Comment: MySql <> Sql Server.

Comment: Could n't get you

Comment: Which is it - mysql or sql server? It cannot be both.

Comment: On what criteria you were mentioning 2017-03-27,2017-03-30 and 2017-03-31 as holidays?

Comment: no no .Actually user want's to see much sales he has made this week,month and year